# AutoDetect USB Insert and Removal in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need to detect when a USB Device is removed or inserted from my program.
I have made some research and [found this](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2211) but don't know how to implement/use it.
could someone help me out probably with a function that would return true on USB Insert and false on Removal so that i can call a Timer to check that function every second?
Using Delphi XE7.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the code you linked? Or read the documentation on MSDN? Do you know the difference between polling and notification? I ask because I suspect you are unclear on all of this. It will pay to understand these details before attempting to go further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an instance of TComponentUSB. Assign two event handlers to OnUSBArrival and OnUSBRemove events. Execute appropriate code in event handlers. Note that polling with TTimer is not needed.
Code sketch:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    CUSB: ComponentUSB;
    procedure USBArrival(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  end;
```

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CUSB := ComponentUSB.Create(Self);
  CUSB.OnUSBArrival = USBArrival;
end;

procedure TMyForm.USBArrival(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'I''m here now!';
end;
```